# Special case pattern rules in Makefile

Tags: makefile, rule

I have a generic rule for files with a given extension, but I want to add special cases for files with a prefix.  I tried this:

```
special-%.dat: special-%.raw
    echo "Running rule 1"

%.dat:
    echo "Running rule 2"
```

but when I run `make special-1.dat`, it ignores the first rule and runs the second.  Switching the order of the rules makes no difference.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct?  There's no way a target `out-1.dat` will use a pattern `special-%.dat`: they don't match.

Comment: Good point; I copied and pasted the Makefile and the command line from slightly different versions.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Does the file `special-1.raw` exist?  If that file doesn't exist (and you have no rule that can create it) make will never choose this rule because the prerequisite is not available.  That's not an error in itself: only if make can find NO rule that can build this target will it fail.

Running `make -d` will show you exactly how make is considering every target and its prerequisites, recursively.